# Apache Ignite Upgrade

Tags: ignite

I'm experimenting with Apache Ignite 1.6 and Ignite 2.1.

I was able to create a cluster and work with Ignite 1.6 with ZooKeeper Based Discovery.

I'm tried to create the Ignite 2.1 cluster with ZooKeeper Based Discovery on the same nodes but it fails with below error.

I have Killed all the nodes in Ignite 1.6 cluster.

Following is the error message:

```
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a97e9a4c9d73d40ce76d1504c14ba1940 stopped OK
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Grid uptime: 00:00:06:777


class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:957)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:350)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:302)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1775)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:977)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1896)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1648)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:994)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:880)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:779)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:649)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:618)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [], reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:300)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:837)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1770)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=1.6.0, rmtBuildVer=2.1.0, locNodeAddrs=[node1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1, /<<ip-addr1>>], rmtNodeAddrs=[node1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1, /<<ip-addr1>>], locNodeId=d560e617-67b1-4900-9f78-beb181e65f23, rmtNodeId=fa1ede5a-1f95-4884-830f-99cd1c61fe63]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1759)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:910)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:358)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1834)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    ... 13 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
```

Following is my config file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.zk.TcpDiscoveryZookeeperIpFinder">
                    <property name="zkConnectionString" value=“<<zkhost>>:2181"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Now, unable to start any of these clusters.
Failing with same error message.

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved.

There were some background processes running on the node with Ignite 1.6.
(Visior service was also running even though I exited from the client).

Found all the processes with the below command and killed

```
ps -ef | grep "ignite"
```